# DAX - How to create two outputs based on two variables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Getting my head around DAX at the moment.
This is my problem. its a pricing file for material is costed using Standard costs (S) and Average costs (V) although I need to review the latest actual cost of the material if the material pricing type is average (V).

This can be achieved with a simple if statement =IF('Pricing_File'[Purchase Price.Actual Cost]>'Pricing_File'[MovAvgPrice],'Pricing_File'[Purchase Price.Actual Cost],'Pricing_File'[MovAvgPrice])

**But want I want is a DAX statement is this**

If S (standard costed) then standard cost) - if V then ('Pricing_File'[Purchase Price.Actual Cost]>'Pricing_File'[MovAvgPrice],'Pricing_File'[Purchase Price.Actual Cost],'Pricing_File'[MovAvgPrice])

Not sure if I need to use calculate or If functions with &&

[image: sample of pricing file]

thanks in advance for help

[image: Error from suggested code]

Hey Guys, I have got it working but sometimes it doesn't work?

see below

working
[image: Working]

and not working, its a little strange

[image: Not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add another column (a calculated column) to the data table this can be done like this:

```
NewColumn = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    [Pricing Control] = "V" && [ActualCost] > [MovAvgPrice], [Actual Cost],
    [Pricing Contro] = "V", [MovAvgPrice],
    [Standard Cost]
)
```

This providing all the referenced columns are in the same data table. Otherwise the code will look slightly different. This could also be done in Power Query, though, again, that code would look completely different.

Comment: Hi Oscar I got the code to work but substituting the ; for a , thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It used to be a language setting thing (if you used ; or ,) but in newer versions of PBI it seems like former ;-users now also use ,
However, our IT-dep is a bit slow in updating versions so we're still running April 2019 version...

Comment: HI Oscar I have a little problem with the code. sometimes it works and other times it doesn't,

Comment: Ok, that's a bit vague. What are the cases when it doesnt work? Are all column in the correct format? Are all etries in the colums correct? Whats the pattern of rows when the code doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry oscar,it was a formatting error, sorry for the delay in responding

Answer (score 0):

In dax we need use CALCULATE if
the expression must be evaluated in a modified filter context.